# Advantages of using pixel tracking mechanism versus regular HTTP GET API call for client side tracking

Tags: rest, architecture, analytics

Pixel tracking method seems to be gaining traction recently especially in the field of marketing and analytics.

For client side tracking internally (tracking system is not opened to be used by public), what are the advantages of using pixel to track *(downloading a 1 pixel image and passing all params that we are interested in tracking in the image url)* versus regular old http get call and passing the get parameter in a message queue to be processed later.